# Recommended Transition from FSM to ML

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, fsm, towers-of-hanoi

I have been doing a bit of machine learning stuff with tensorflow and tflearn, and decided to revisit an old problem. the specific problem is writing a program that can effectively solve the towers of hanoi from any state to any other state. I have previously done this using a FSM but would like to take a crack at it using ML, and was wondering if there is there any particular type of ANN I should try first?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.jurnalteknologi.utm.my/index.php/jurnalteknologi/article/download/1071/1040

Comment: Thank, I'll take a look